# Error composing FullCalendar

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, composer-php, fullcalendar

I get an error when I try to add FullCalendar to my composer.json

[UnexpectedValueException]
Could not parse version constraint >=~2: Invalid version string "~2"

When I remove the FullCalendar from my require section everything works fine. 
I'm not exactly a composer wizard so any help would be useful.

```
"require": {
  "php": ">=5.5.9",
  "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
  "laravelcollective/html": "5.*",

  "symfony/finder": "^3.0",
  "symfony/yaml": "^3.0",

  "firephp/firephp-core": "^0.4.0",
  "wpb/string-blade-compiler": "3.3.0",
  "mpdf/mpdf": "^6.1",
  "PHPOffice/PHPExcel": "^1.8",
  "mgargano/simplehtmldom": "^1.5",

  "components/font-awesome": "dev-master",
  "components/modernizr": "2.8.3",

  "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.3",

  "bower-asset/animate.css": "dev-master",
  "bower-asset/autosize": "dev-master",
  "bower-asset/autogrow": "1.0.2",
  "bower-asset/chartjs": "dev-master",
  "bower-asset/eventemitter": "dev-master",
  "bower-asset/framework7": "dev-master",
  "bower-asset/jsanimatedmodal": "dev-master",
  "bower-asset/jquery": "3.1.1",
  "bower-asset/jquery-idletimer": "dev-master",
  "bower-asset/jquery-ui": "dev-master",
  "bower-asset/jquery.transit": "dev-master",
  "bower-asset/magnific-popup": "dev-master",
  "bower-asset/moment": "^2.1",
  "bower-asset/OwlCarouselBower": "dev-master",
  "bower-asset/photoswipe": "dev-master",
  "bower-asset/platform": "dev-master",
  "bower-asset/select2": "dev-master",
  "bower-asset/selectize": "dev-master",
  "bower-asset/spin.js": "dev-master",
  "bower-asset/spinkit": "dev-master",
  "bower-asset/underscore": "dev-master",
  "bower-asset/vue": "1.0.28",
  "bower-asset/jquery-file-download": "^1.4",
  "bower-asset/tooltipster": "^4.1",
  "bower-asset/vue-multiselect": "^1.1",
  "nnnick/chartjs": "^2.2",
  "phpoffice/phpword": "^0.13.0",
  "peekmo/jsonpath": "dev-master",
  "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "dev-master",
  "bower-asset/jquery-simple-slideshow": "^1.0"
```

},

Comment: How are you attempting to add it?

Comment: I just add bower-asset/fullcalendar : "dev-master" to my require section in my composer.json and type: composer install. I've also tried using: composer require bower-asset/fullcalendar. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run

```
composer self-update
```

Probably your version of composer doesn't parse the tilde operator correctly.

Read more [here](https://github.com/fxpio/composer-asset-plugin/issues/270)

Comment: Thanx but my composer is up-to-date (1.4.1)